# I am trying to take a sum or count of transactions per year ,I have this code but i need help in getting it right

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select (cus_name||bra_code),
  sum(case when tra_date between '01jan2019' AND '31Dec2019' THEN 2019 else 0 end) as o  
  sum(case when tra_date between '01jan2018' AND '31Dec2018' THEN 2018 else 0 end)) as F 
  sum(case when tra_date between '01jan2017' AND '31Dec2017' THEN 2017 else 0 end)as H
from stg.v_src_pend_tra@exadata_new
group by cus_name,bra_code
```

Comment: This looks like Oracle, not MySQL so I changed the tags.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: There's an extra closing parenthesis after the second `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need amounts.  In this case, `1` for each transaction:

```
select (cus_name || bra_code),
       sum(case when tra_date between date '2019-01-01' and date '2019-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as o, 
       sum(case when tra_date between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-12-31' then 1 else 0 end)) as F,
       sum(case when tra_date between date '2017-01-01' and date '2017-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as H
from stg.v_src_pend_tra@exadata_new
group by cus_name, bra_code;
```

Note that I also changed the date constants so they conform to ISO standards.

Comment: It still gives an error " FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: select cus_num,bra_code,tra_date,
        case
           when tra_date between '01jan2019' AND '31Dec2019' THEN 2019 
              when tra_date between '01jan2018' AND '31Dec2018' THEN 2018
                when tra_date between '01jan2017' AND '31Dec2017' THEN 2017
                 end  NEW_DATE
from stg.v_src_pend_tra@exadata_new                                                                                        Im am thinking i can do this then count when 2019 ,count when 2018

Comment: @Vandako . . . There is a typo in your query with no commas at the end of the expressions.  I fixed this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE` literals rather than trying to rely on an implicit conversion of a string (i.e. `'01jan2019'`) to a date.

If you filter `BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'` then this will get all dates from `2019-01-01T00:00:00` to `2019-12-31T00:00:00`. If your dates are always set so the time component is at midnight (all date values always have a time component in Oracle) then this will work but if you have a non-midnight time component then you will miss values between `2019-12-31T00:00:01` and `2019-12-31T23:59:59`.

To solve this you need to use:

```sql
SELECT cus_name || bra_code,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN tra_date >= DATE '2019-01-01'
         AND  tra_date <  DATE '2020-01-01'
         THEN tra_date
         END
       ) AS o, 
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN tra_date >= DATE '2018-01-01'
         AND  tra_date <  DATE '2019-01-01'
         THEN tra_date
         END
       ) AS f,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN tra_date >= DATE '2017-01-01'
         AND  tra_date <  DATE '2018-01-01'
         THEN tra_date
         END
       ) AS H
FROM   stg.v_src_pend_tra@exadata_new
GROUP BY cus_name, bra_code;
```

*(You also need commas after each expression in the `SELECT` part of the statement and to remove the extra closing bracket.)*